# How to display multiple notifications in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification

I use flutter_local_notifications package to set notifications. I have a list  of notification.In my case, my app shows only the last notification every 5 seconds , but I want to show the last 10 notifications. How can I do this ?

this my code :

```
Future<void> repeatNotification() async {
    var androidChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'CHANNEL_ID 3',
      'CHANNEL_NAME 3',
      "CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION 3",
      playSound: true,
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('notification'),
      styleInformation: DefaultStyleInformation(true, true),
    );
    var iosChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        android: androidChannelSpecifics, iOS: iosChannelSpecifics);
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = localStorage.getString('access_token');
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    };
    var response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse(ApiUtil.GET_ALERT), headers: headers);
    var data = json.decode(response.body);
    var dataa = (data['data']['data']['data'][0]);
    if (data['status'] == 200) {
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          0,
          dataa['boxName'],
          dataa['alert_description'],    
          platformChannelSpecifics);
    } else {
      print("no message");
    }
   
  }
```

and this the response from the server :

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "message": " success",
    "data": {
        "data": {
            "current_page": 1,
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": 69,
                    "user_id": 53,
                    "boxIdentifiant": 1924589682265310,
                    "boxName": "box Malta",
                    "alert_date": "2021-05-30",
                    "alert_time": "09:40",
                    "alert_description": "Panne high",
                    "alert_level": "info"
                },
                {
                    "id": 68,
                    "user_id": 53,
                    "boxIdentifiant": 1924589682265310,
                    "boxName": "box Malta",
                    "alert_date": "2021-05-30",
                    "alert_time": "09:40",
                    "alert_description": "Panne Pression",
                    "alert_level": "warning"
                },
                {
                    "id": 67,
                    "user_id": 53,
                    "boxIdentifiant": 1924589682265309,
                    "boxName": "box masr",
                    "alert_date": "2021-05-30",
                    "alert_time": "09:40",
                    "alert_description": "Panne Pression",
                    "alert_level": "warning"
                },
                {
                    "id": 66,
                    "user_id": 53,
                    "boxIdentifiant": 1924589682265308,
                    "boxName": "box libya",
                    "alert_date": "2021-05-30",
                    "alert_time": "09:40",
                    "alert_description": "Panne Pression",
                    "alert_level": "warning"
                },
                {
                    "id": 62,
                    "user_id": 53,
                    "boxIdentifiant": 1924589682265245,
                    "boxName": "Box Sfax",
                    "alert_date": "2021-05-30",
                    "alert_time": "09:40",
                    "alert_description": "Panne Pression",
                    "alert_level": "warning"
                },
                {
                    "id": 61,
                    "user_id": 53,
                    "boxIdentifiant": 1924589682265243,
                    "boxName": "Box Tunis",
                    "alert_date": "2021-05-30",
                    "alert_time": "09:40",
                    "alert_description": "Panne Pression Roux",
                    "alert_level": "info"
                },
                {
                    "id": 58,
                    "user_id": 53,
                    "boxIdentifiant": 1924589682265244,
                    "boxName": "Box Office",
                    "alert_date": "2021-05-30",
                    "alert_time": "09:40",
                    "alert_description": "Panne Pression Roux",
                    "alert_level": "warning"
                },
                {
                    "id": 57,
                    "user_id": 53,
                    "boxIdentifiant": 1924589682265244,
                    "boxName": "Box Office",
                    "alert_date": "2021-05-30",
                    "alert_time": "09:40",
                    "alert_description": "Panne batterie",
                    "alert_level": "danger"
                },
                {
                    "id": 56,
                    "user_id": 53,
                    "boxIdentifiant": 1924589682265300,
                    "boxName": "box Maroc",
                    "alert_date": "2021-05-30",
                    "alert_time": "09:40",
                    "alert_description": "Panne batterie",
                    "alert_level": "danger"
                },
                {
                    "id": 54,
                    "user_id": 53,
                    "boxIdentifiant": 1924589682265246,
                    "boxName": "boxt mannouba",
                    "alert_date": "2021-05-30",
                    "alert_time": "09:45",
                    "alert_description": "Panne roue",
                    "alert_level": "info"
                }
            ],
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

In this line you are taking the data to display as notification

var dataa = (data['data']['data']['data'][0])

And you are taking only the first element by specifing index 0

Then you show the notification

To show all the notification you have to cycle throw your data array at any index then show the notification.. something like this

For(int i = 0; i < data['data']['data']['data'].lemgth; i++) {
var data = data['data']['data']['data'][i];

//Display notification with data
}

Comment: Slow Looper main: Activity com.example.tracar/.MainActivity is 774ms late (wall=35ms running=14ms ClientTransaction{ lifecycleRequest=android.app.servertransaction.StopActivityItem }) because of 9 msg ... @Patrick Gharapetians Gheshlagh

Comment: var bataa = (data['data']['data']['data']);
    notifs = bataa;
    print(id);
    
    print(notifs.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < notifs.length; i++) {
      if (data['status'] == 200) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            0,
            bataa['boxName'],
            bataa['alert_description'],
            //  RepeatInterval.everyMinute,
            platformChannelSpecifics);
        // }
      } else {
        print("no message");
      }
    }